# -a^b and pedmas/bodmas order of operation?

Tags: computational-mathematics

Really silly question but didnt know where else to ask. I am looking back at some basic definite integration stuff and have stumped myself at the most basic of things (I have a knack for doing this kind of thing to myself). Lets say I am met with -x^2 and x is +2.Following bodmas, do I treat the minus as part of the number and square it to get a positive result or treat the minus sign as a multiplication of negative 1 and hence proceed to square first, resulting in a negative answer...?

upon further research I have found out from wikipedia that there isn't a standard for this...within the context of an integration question I would get 2 different answers, hence the confusion. Ive never really given this any thought in the past. I appreciate any responses.

Comment: e.g lets say I integrate (2x/3 + 3x)dx , in this context what would be the correct way?

Comment: Thank you my friend. That does make more sense actually, yes.

Comment: I meant to write : Your second choice is the standard one: $−x^2=(−1)x^2 $ not $-x^2=(−x)^2$.  Sorry about the typo, but I think you understood  it anyway. I am deleting my comment with the typo.

Comment: Do not write $\int  (2x/3 + 3x)\;dx$ if you mean $\int (2x/(3 + 3x))\;dx$.  Since $(2x/3 + 3x) = (2/3 + 3) x = (11/3) x$.

Comment: I meant ( ( (2*x)/3 ) + (3*x) )dx